# can't access source object when window.postMessage in Edge

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

I am currently using `Edge 44.18362`, I have an authentication window, and a parent window which opens it, once the authentication is done I am posting the message to the parent (opener window) like this:

```
$window.opener.postMessage(data,URL);
```

and I am listening to the event in the parent window like this:

```
window.addEventListener('message', someFunc, false);
```

and `someFunc()` is defined like this:

```
function someFunc(windowData){
//here I am accessing source as windowData.source
}
```

I am trying to access the `source` attribute of `MessageEvent` to access the URL and stuff.
In Chrome/Firefox I am able to access `source` object and functionality works fine, but when it comes to Edge I am not able to access `source` object and I see this error in console.
`!0:` 
[image] 
What is going wrong here, what can be done to fix this?

Added try-catch around the block of code, this is the error I see.
[image]

Comment: `window.opener.postMessage(data);` - shouldn't there be a second argument to that call?

Comment: @JaromandaX I have edited the question, yes it takes 2 parameters.

Comment: Can't repro on  Edge 44.18362 The window object is correctly logged. Though, I did set `data` to the empty string `""` and `url` to wildcard `"*"`. Are you trying to access some property of that WindowProxy object? Also why do you want to retrieve this exactly? Can't you just give names to your `open`ed windows?

Comment: Please give more details on the concerned code

Comment: What more details you are looking for? I added most of the details which I felt are necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I made a test with the following code sample and it can work well in Edge:

**Page1.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script>
        function openChild() {
            var childwin = window.open('Page2.html', 'popup', 'height=300px, width=500px');
        }

        window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
            let txt = document.querySelector('#txtMsg');
            txt.value = `Name is ${event.data.pName} Age is  ${event.data.pAge}`;
            console.log(event.source);  //update: get event.source
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <input type='button' id='btnopen' value='Open child' onclick='openChild();' />
            <input type='text' id='txtMsg' />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Page2.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script>
        function sendMessage() {
            let msg = { pName: "Bob", pAge: "35" };
            window.opener.postMessage(msg, 'http://domain_name/Page1.html')
            window.opener.focus();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <fieldset>            
            <input type='button' id='btnSendMsg' value='Send Message' onclick='sendMessage();' />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Result:**

[image]

You could refer to the sample, if still not working, please provide a minimal sample which can **reproduce** the issue. With only the above code you provide, I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, can you mention which Edge version you tested this on? 
And you are nowhere accessing event.source in the above code, the problem is I am not able to access the source of the event.

Comment: I tested it with Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0, Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18362 on Windows 10.

Comment: You are nowhere accessing event.source in the above code, the problem is I am not able to access the source of the event.

Comment: I add this line in Page1.html: `console.log(event.source);`, please see the edit. It also can get the `source` object, you could check [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xy7lG.png). What about refer to my sample and see if it works on your Edge browser? If still not working, I think I need a more specific sample of your code which can reproduce the issue to see how to help.

Comment: The same example works for me as well, our application code is in angularjs, so I am using $window provided by angularjs instead of window Object of browser, will that be an issue?

Comment: It might be. From the explain of [`$window`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window), there's little difference between `$window` and browser's `window` object. `window` is globally available but `$window` can be overridden, removed or mocked for testing. You could try to change it to browser `window` object to see if it helps. But it's hard to say if this is the real issue as we only have very limited code you providing.

Comment: Added a screenshot of the error after adding try-catch around the code, I see <permission-denied>, but not sure what to infer out of this.

Comment: I think the issue is not related with `<permission-denied>`. I can also see `<permission-denied>` [in Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOhRi.png) but I can access `event.source`. Also [in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0Yzm.png), the arguments seem can't be accessed as well. So I think that's not the root cause.